# discord.py bot does not load videos in embed

Tags: api, discord, discord.py, bots, reddit

hey there i hope ur having a gr8 time my discord.py bot doesnt load video data it fetches from an api i want the discord.py bot to not load the reddits which have videos as url because ofc the bot cant load a video in the embed besides the videos are disguisting and nobody watches those.
attaching a code snippet:

```
    @commands.command(name='aww',
                      aliases=["aw", "cute", "cutepics"])
    async def aww(self, ctx):
        sub_submissions = reddit.subreddit('aww').hot()
        post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 100)
        for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
            submission = next(x for x in sub_submissions if not x.stickied)
        e = discord.Embed(
            title=f'Your request!',
            description=f'{submission.title}\n{submission.selftext}')
        e.set_image(url=submission.url)
        e.set_footer(text=f"OFC!Thank dove#1565 for this amazing quickie!? \nRequested by {ctx.author}")
        await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

i have no other problem in the code what so ever i use praw to fetch data from api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your requesting is impossible. Discord's API doesn't allow you to attach videos to embeds.